# REST Android method not allowed on GET method

Tags: java, android, json, rest

I have an android app and REST server made in Spring Tool Suite. REST is connecting to database and returns list of Json objects depending on the query in the GET request.
This is my REST response to GET method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/short", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public  Map<String,List<Temperature>> shortPeriod(@RequestParam(value = "time",required = false)
         @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss")  Date time){
    Map<String, List<Temperature>> results = new HashMap<String, List<Temperature>>();
    List<Temperature> temperatureList = new ArrayList<Temperature>();   
    System.out.println("TEST!");
    try {
        temperatureList = dataServices.getEntityList(time,"short");
        results.put("data", temperatureList);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return results;
}
```

and this is how i connect on android

```
       String tempUrl = new String("http://" + IP + ":8080/" + "RestServer/temperature/" + tableName + "?time=" + urlQueryTimestamp);

        String encodedUrlTemp = tempUrl.replace(" ", "%20");
        String encodedUrl = encodedUrlTemp.replace("-", ":");

        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.connect();
```

I have put test prints and It's working ok till connection.connect();

The url looks something like this

http://192.168.1.106:8080/RestServer/temperature/short?time=2015:06:05%2010:20:03

I'm printing "url" variable before connecting and when I take that url and paste it into chrome I get normal response as I should. But when I'm trying to connect in my app I get "method not allowed". I have found some solutions about that exception and it's usually problem with POST method not implemented on server, but with same url i get normal response on chrome on my computer and even on my mobile chrome on smartphone.
Other thing is that I have one other server with hardcoded json data for testing and i can connect normally there when there is no query in http request, so only this 
http://192.168.1.106:8080/RestServer/temperature/short

So my assumption is that chrome escapes some strings internally or sets up some header infromation by itself when using a query, and android doesn't. Server doesn't even records request as one I pasted in code above, it's like im sending wrong url.

One other thing, I tried using url encoder from android library but it escapes some letters that shouldn't be escaped and I read that it escapes it for html, so I'm doing it manually(maybe I'm doing it wrong).

I turned off the firewall, checked ip adress dozen of times and I have no ideas more.

Comment: try it without your timestamp first, I have run into a problem where I get a 400 error from the server due to illegal characters in a timestamp, if this is the case then make sure you fully urlencode your request string before sending. - On a side note take a look at the GSON and OkHttpClient packages, they make things like this far easier :-)

Comment: @dave thanks for reply.
I have tried without timestamp and it's working so I'm pretty sure it's encoding problem in query. I'm alredy using Gson and I'll take a look at OkHttp if it helps but if i don't find any other solution I'll probably send timestamp in millis and convert it on android and server

Answer (score 0):

After trying absolutely every solution I found with escapeing, changing library's and reading about URI's and URL's, I have found the solution on android developer documentation page where it says:

> HttpURLConnection uses the GET method by default. **It will use POST if
>   setDoOutput(true) has been called**. Other HTTP methods (OPTIONS, HEAD,
>   PUT, DELETE and TRACE) can be used with setRequestMethod(String).

Hope this helps to someone